# Dynamic where clause with two entity

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I need a filter between two entity. 
Have two tables 1.User 2.Product
Product map with the User table.

I am going to create a dynamic where filter.

I need to find out all the users which have 'test' product.

Conditions: if userFilter count is 0 then I need all test product with the respected user.

If userFilter is there and productFilter is there then below code is working but if userFilter is not there and productFilter is there then it returning 0 row. How can I find the users which have test product? ?

Here is my Code.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetFilter()
        {
            var userFilters = new List<Filter>()
            {
                new Filter { PropertyName = "Username" ,
                    Operation = Op .Equals, Value = "Karan"  },
            };

            var productfilter = new List<Filter>()
            {
                new Filter { PropertyName = "Name" ,
                    Operation = Op .Equals, Value = "Test product"  }
            };

            Func<User, bool> deleg = x => true;
            Func<Product, bool> delegProduct = x => true;

            if (userFilters.Count > 0)
            {
                deleg = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<User>(userFilters).Compile();
            }

            if (productfilter.Count > 0)
            {
                delegProduct = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Product>(productfilter).Compile();
            }

            var resultt = _localmarketEntities.Users.Where(deleg)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Id,
                    x.Username,
                    Product = x.Products.Where(delegProduct).Select(y => new
                    {
                        y.Id,
                        y.Name
                    }).ToList()
                })
                .ToList();

            return Ok(resultt);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged with entity-framework this is all Linq to objects stuff. Unless you don't mean to do all your filtering in memory? Anyway what happens if you remove `.Where(deleg)` from you code, that should be the same as having no filters, does it still bring nothing back?

Comment: If there is userFilter then I need to use deleg. That's why is there. So if I remove it then I can't filter it by userFilter. Make sense?

Comment: What does "`userFilter` is not there" mean?

Comment: Consider userFilter has nothing. Means no filter related to the user.
Func<User, bool> deleg = x => true; will be executed by default.

Comment: Then your code looks fine and I think the problem isn't where you think - perhaps get LINQPad or use debugger, see what `_localmarketEntities.Users.Where(deleg).Count()` returns when `userFilters.Count` is zero.

Comment: _localmarketEntities.Users.Where(deleg).Count() returns all the row if there is a filter otherwise it return 0. In this case if i filter obviouse  x.Products.Where(delegProduct) not work.

But I want products when student filter is not there. 

Did you understand what I want?

Comment: I understand what you want. I don't think you are interpreting what is happening correctly. If you literally put in `_localmarketEntities.Users.Where(x => true)` what happens?

Comment: `if (UserName field in User table then below code will execute)
 {deleg = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<User>(userFilters).Compile();
 }`
So, in this case, consider UserName field not into the User table and Name property into the Product table. 
Based on this filter I want all the User data which Product name = "Test product".
When I execute, did not get any row but data is there in the database table. 

If UserName field is there in the User table then will get the result. 
But I want if there is no filter related to the User table then how can I achieve? 
did you now understand?

Comment: Maybe it can help you: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: are you need all users that have test product when userFiler count is 0 am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correct, you need all users that have test product when userFiler count is 0.

```
List<User> res;
var user = _localmarketEntities.Users.Where(deleg).ToList();
if (user.Count == 0) {
    res = _localmarketEntities.Products.Where(delegProduct).Select(q => new User() {
       Id = q.Id,
       Username = q.Username,
       Product = q
    }).ToList();
}
else {
    res = _localmarketEntities.Users.Where(deleg)
          .Select(x => new
          {
              x.Id,
              x.Username,
              Product = x.Products.Where(delegProduct).Select(y => new
              {
                  y.Id,
                  y.Name
              }).ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
}
```